# How do I display a web page within app inventor 2?

Tags: android, app-inventor

I've tried using 'activitystarter' "android.intent.action.VIEW"

But it just links to the website connecting to the browser app like Chrome.

I would like to display certain part of the web page within the app, just like when using google book API.

Is it possible only when using an API?

Is there an alternative way to do so without using an API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `webviewer` component to display a webpage

A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .

Also do the tutorials http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html to learn the basics of App Inventor, then try something and follow the [Top 5 Tips: How to learn App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)